# How to scale GameObjects to Camera in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, scale

I've searched all over for this problem and mostly found answers relating to U.I. scaling, which I am already aware of.

I am creating a game and want every scene to fit on one screen. I am running into problems where the screen size messes with the game scene. Just as an example, here's a very basic scene and how I want it to always look:
[what i want all the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQTjU.png)

but if you alter the screen size the camera moves and it looks like this:
[what happens when you scale the screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lpg6.png)

I want those white boxes that are boundaries to stay constantly at the edge, plus anything else I want in the scene should scale with them.

Does anyone know any methods or functions in Unity to achieve what I want? Thanks.

I tried many different ways of scaling the GameObjects but couldn't find anything that kept them in unison with the camera. This included changing the camera size and accessing and changing the width/height of objects via their Collider2D components and scaling it with the camera. In the end they didn't achieve what I wanted.

EDIT: turns out you can adjust the aspect ratio in the Unity Game tab, in case anyone else has this problem. Change "free aspect" to 16:9 or whatever works.

Thanks for the helpful replies regardless :)

Comment: You can use (I know you don't want UI) the same principle the canvas scales does: Use a certain reference resolution and on runtime scale your object according to the actual screen dimensions

Comment: where would i look into learning how to do that? on runtime i assume you mean on the Start method?

Comment: For starters you can look into the [source code](https://github.com/liuqiaosz/Unity/blob/master/UGUI%E6%BA%90%E4%BB%A3%E7%A0%81/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Layout/CanvasScaler.cs) and then adapt it according to your needs. Though actually you could even use UI for your use case since everything is 2D anyway .. what would speak against it?

Comment: This might be helpful, I remember watching it a while back https://youtu.be/gFWQHordrtA